# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $x \in X$, $A \subseteq X$. Show for $\delta>0$,$P=\{x \in X : d(x,A)=\inf\{(d(x,a):a \in A\} \leq \delta\}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $y \in P^c$ i.e., $z=\inf\{d(x,a) : a \in A\}>\delta$. Choose $r=z-\delta>0$. Let $w \in B(y,r)$. We will prove that $$w \in P^c \Longleftrightarrow q=\inf\{d(w,a) : a \in A\} >\delta.$$
Assume $q \leq \delta$, i.e,., there exists $a' \in A$ with $d(w,a') \leq \delta$. Then
\begin{align*}
z &\leq d(y,a')\\
&\leq d(y,w)+d(w,a')\\
&<z-\delta+\delta\\
&=\delta.  
\end{align*}
(Contradiction with $\delta<z$). Therefore $q>\delta$ and $P$ is closed.

Is my proving true or there is a missing step ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Prove that $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is continuous. Denote such map by $\theta$. Then $P = \theta^{-1} ((-\infty,\delta])$ is closed because it is an inverse image of a closed set under a continuous map.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y\in P^c$, then $d(y,A)>\delta$. Take $\epsilon=\frac{d(y,A)-\delta}{2}$, it's easy to check that the open ball $B(y,\epsilon)\subset P^c$:
\begin{align*}
y'\in B(y,\epsilon) &\Rightarrow d(y',a)\geq d(y,a)-\epsilon,\;\forall a\in A\\
&\Rightarrow d(y',a)\geq d(y,A)-\epsilon =\frac{d(y,A)+\delta}{2},\;\forall a\in A\\
&\Rightarrow d(y',A)\geq \frac{d(y,A)+\delta}{2}> \delta.
\end{align*}